# Modification of the headline line-height in the Compass vertical rhythm module

Tags: sass, mixins

One thing nagged me about the compass vertical rhythm module; in the case the headline is too long and it occupies more than one line the line-height between the two lines looks way too massive and off.

Based on the following [article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/14/technical-web-typography-guidelines-and-techniques/), I've taken the `adjust-font-size-to` mixin source and modified and simplified things a bit (e.g. stripped out the relative font sizing part). I just wanted to get a basic working alternative take to get the possibility to get a smaller and tighter line-height for headlines with two or more lines.

```css
@mixin adjust-headline-size-to($to-size, $from-size: $base-font-size, $magic-number: $base-line-height) {
  font-size: $font-unit * $to-size / $from-size;
  line-height: $magic-number / $to-size;
}
```

The question is on the code side.  Are things laid out in a clean way and on the line-height side is the math behind correct, or would there be a more reasonable and reliable way to keep the rhythm while minimizing the line-height in contrast to the regular one from `adjust-font-size-to`?

To illustrate what I tried to accomplish, here's a sample HTML snippet:

```html
<p>Mr. Worf, you sound like a man who's asking his friend if he can start dating his sister. A lot of things can change in twelve years, Admiral. How long can two people talk about nothing?</p>
<h2 class="testheadshort">Short Headline</h2>
<p>Mr. Worf, you sound like a man who's asking his friend if he can start dating his sister. A lot of things can change in twelve years, Admiral. How long can two people talk about nothing?</p>
<h2 class="testheadlongregular">This one is a bit longer headline to show of the effect with the regular mixin</h3>
<p>Mr. Worf, you sound like a man who's asking his friend if he can start dating his sister. A lot of things can change in twelve years, Admiral. How long can two people talk about nothing?</p>
<h2 class="testheadlongmod">This one is a bit longer headline to show of the effect with the regular mixin</h3>
<p>Mr. Worf, you sound like a man who's asking his friend if he can start dating his sister. A lot of things can change in twelve years, Admiral. How long can two people talk about nothing?</p>
```

The used Scss is:

```css
.testheadshort,
.testheadshortregular {
    @include adjust-font-size-to(29px);
}

.testheadlongmod {
    @include adjust-headline-size-to(29px);
}
```

The first two `h2` use the regular `adjust-font-size-to` mixin while the last uses the mixin i wrote in my initial question. The resulting CSS for `.testheadlongmod` is plain simple:

```css
.testheadlongmod {
  font-size: 1.38095em;
  line-height: 1.06897;
}
```

And to illustrate the difference in visual representation a screenshot in the end:

[image: sample of the usage of adjust-font-size-to and adjust-headline-size-to]

As you can see the `line-height` for the second headline, where the regular `adjust-font-size-to` mixin is used, is way off.